# Error in Eclipse:Android for Dummies

Tags: android

I am having the error:"Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Given below is the related file:

ReminderListActivity.java

```
package com.example.taskreminder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);
    final String[] items;
    items = new String[] {“Foo”,“Bar”,“Fizz”,“Bin”};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.reminder_row,   R.id.text1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_reminder_list, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The error is on "items = new String[] {“Foo”,“Bar”,“Fizz”,“Bin”};"
"Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"

Can some one help with this?

Comment: Removed the double quotes and typed them manually! Works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove double quotes from this line and give it again

```
items = new String[] {"Foo","Bar","Fizz","Bin"};
```

Comment: hey sorry for that double quotes i mentioned. this is the problem instead of this  ' “ ' we have to use ' " '

Comment: yes, actually he copied directly from text that's y the error came if we given manually the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You've got some funky quotes in your code, more precisely the `“`'s and `”`'s (instead of the plain `"`'s). This should do the trick:

```
items = new String[] {"Foo","Bar","Fizz","Bin"};
```

Comment: Great! It's usually the case if you copy a snippet from documents/pdfs, where the quotes have been "visually enhanced". :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you copy/pasted the code from the book. :)
Try manually to add the quotes. it should be double quotes like this: " ", not like this “ “